How to show in bar only the current status of an item in powerbi
I am a beginner in powerbi, please help me with enough detail to solve this scenario:
Suppose that I have several records in a table like these:



Item
Status
Date
Semester




C1
Ready
12/06/2024
S1-2024


C2
In progress
09/06/2024
S1-2024


C1
In progress
08/06/2024
S1-2024



I need a bar chart that only shows the most recent status of all the items in a current period of time in this case "semester", in the example for S1-2024 the data table must be:



Item
Status
Date
Semester




C1
Ready
12/06/2024
S1-2024


C2
In progress
09/06/2024
S1-2024



How can accomplish that?
Thank you in advance for your help.
I was trying to understand this: text but I do not know how to use it in the bar chart

you can try to create a new column
Column = 
VAR _max =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Item] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( 'Table'[Date] = _max, "y" )

then when you add the column to filter and select 'y', then you will get the most recent status

